# Unable to update results in Testrail with ProtractorJS

Tags: jasmine, protractor, testrail

I am unable to update the Protractor tests' results in Testrail.
I have seen various npm modules, very confusing - various writers mentioned different npm modules.

Environment:
1. ProtractorJS (NPM based)
2. Testrail

1. Installed - npm install protractor-testrail-promise
2. Created a javascript page object - loginPage.js

And inside of the loginPage.js, I have written very basic test to verify.

```
loginPage.js - is below:

var TestRail = require("protractor-testrail-promise");

var loginPage = function () {
var testrail = new TestRail("https://myproject.testrail.net", "useremail@email.com", "pw");       
var testCaseId="A644776";
var testResultId="1"; //Equal to Pass
testrail.addResult(testCaseId, testResultId).then(function(body) {
  console.log(body);
  })
});
```

Execpted: The results should be updated in testrail system.

Actual: Update did not happen in Testrail, no error in my VSCode console either.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the prefix "A" for testcaseid.
No prefixes should be added in the code.

```
var TestRail = require("testrail-promise");

var tr = new TestRail('https://myproj.testrail.net', 'dinesh@abc.com', 'werer');             
var obj = {
   "run_id": 001 ,
   "project_id":2,
   "section_name":"My Section", //Immediate section name is fine
   "case_id":  60644 , //Original case id - (View Case)
   "custom_buildno":"B76",
   "status_id":"1", //pass
};
tr.addResultForCase(obj).then(function (err) { console.log('Error ==>', err);});
```